# How to get value from a readonly input with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Supposing I have this input:

```
<input type="text" name="myInput" readonly>
```

How to get value from a readonly input with jQuery please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As usual, just select the element and get the value: `$(":input[type=text][readonly='readonly']").val()`

```js
$(":input[type=text][readonly='readonly']").val('testvalue');

console.log($(":input[type=text][readonly='readonly']").val());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="myInput" readonly>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simple use the `selector` for getting the value.In this solution i used name selector `myInput`.Hope this helps,thanks

```js
var val = $( "input[name='myInput']" ).val() //Getting value using jquery name selector
console.log(val)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="myInput"  value="test" readonly>
```